# Transition from "Temple Judaism" to "Rabbinic Judaism"

Tags: history, mesorah-tradition

In reference to [this comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/174193/what-educational-resources-could-help-someone-who-knows-they-will-time-travel-to/174204?noredirect=1#comment541843_174204) on the Worldbuilding.SE question, ["What educational resources could help someone who knows they will time travel to the future?"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/174193/what-educational-resources-could-help-someone-who-knows-they-will-time-travel-to):

> There is little resemblance between medieval and modern Rabbinic Judaism and the Temple Judaism of the antiquity. For a simple example, Temple Judaism has priests and sacrifices; Rabbinic Judaism has neither priests nor sacrifices. That's one massive difference. For another example, Temple Judaism had nothing even remotely resembling the Talmud and the extremely complicated system of rules and regulations which give Rabbinic Judaism its distinctive color. The entire very elaborate system of halakha is post-classical.

What traditional Jewish sources (if any) would seem to support the contention that Judaism evolved from so-called "Temple Judaism" to so-called "Rabbinic Judaism"?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if there really is little connection (according to possibly some sources) between modern Judaism and ancient Judaism?

Comment: @Harel13 My belief (and I use the word only because I don't feel I have the tools to fully evaluate it ATM) is that _halacha_ -- and thus the essential foundation of Judaism -- is the same as it always has been since G-d gave us the Torah at Sinai. My question is what sources would seem to imply otherwise, with the assumption that such an implication is due to a shallow or mis-understanding of the source.

Comment: "Rabbinic Judaism has neither priests nor sacrifices" is ridiculous.  The only reason we don't bring sacrifices is because the Muslims are in the way.

Comment: @Heshy Well, there's also the fact that we don't have kohanim meyuchasin, for one thing.

Comment: @Meir That's only a rabbinic impediment.

Comment: @DoubleAA Source for that? From the Rambam, Issurei Biah 20:1, it seems not so (since he says that כהני חזקה aren't allowed to eat תרומה דאורייתא, and presumably all the more so to do the avodah).

Comment: @Meir I don't understand your proof from the rambam. According to biblical law kohanei chazaka can do everything since chazaka is a valid deorayta proof. Miderabanan we require higher proof for 'dangerous' activities like eating teruma deorayta or doing avoda. Does anyone dispute that? Why wouldn't chazaka work deorayta?

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe, although the Maggid Mishneh there says דחזקה מהני למה שהיא של דבריהם. You might be right that this itself is a derabbanan, although I'm not sure of that (true of course that chazakah is valid deoraisa, but not all chazakos are created equal).

Comment: @Meir Can you think of any deorayta mekor for their being two different kinds of kohanim mideorayta? Someone is either a kohein or he isn't. If someone doesn't have genealogy proof back to Aharon, then mideorayta either he is or is not a kohein for everything. This is by far the simplest reading of the classical sources.

Comment: @DoubleAA Turns out that, like lots of things, there's a machlokes about that. I see where the Shevet Halevi ([9:253](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1419#p=235), ד"ה ואשיב and following paragraph) cites several different opinions: that indeed this chazakah would be good enough on a deoraisa level (Maharit et al); that it's not, and that at least for avodah, real yichus is needed (Kaftor Vaferach et al); or that today's kohanim aren't even at the level of kohanei chazakah (Maharashdam et al).

Comment: @Meir yes but like I said there's only one simple read of the classical sources. The other opinions are very difficult (and the last opinion isn't applicable to non-ashkenzi kohanim anyway since they weren't in the crusades, and we only need some kohanim to be ok to do avoda)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The place to look for this is in Collected Writings of Rav S.R. Hirsch, the volume on Oral Law (I think Vol. 5 but I can't check it.)

The volume is divided into two parts.

The first part is a critique of H. Graetz's "History of the Jews" the volume discussing the evolution of the Oral Law.

The second part is a critique of Zechariah Frankel's "Darkei Mishna".

In both parts, Rav Hirsch quotes the authors citing various sources and drawing mistaken conclusions.

He then shows why their approaches are mistaken and brings proofs to that effect, and explains the correct understanding of the texts.

If you want a sampling of traditional sources which can be misunderstood to mean that there was a transition from "Temple Judaism" to "Rabbinic Judaism" check out the volume.

One example: Graetz builds a lot upon the assumption that Rabbi Yochanan Ben Zakkai came to do exactly this. In post-churban Judaism, RYbZ felt the need to shift the focus from the Beis Hamikdash to Torah study.
Graetz then brings a number of sources which could superficially be understood to mean this is what he did.

Rav Hirsch then quotes those sources in their context, shows how Graetz misinterpreted them, brings other sources to buttress his arguments, and then explains what RYbZ actually came to do.

And while it's a shame that both Graetz and Frankel were kofrim, they at least knew a lot. Thus they quote sources from all over the place- albeit improperly.
As a result, Rav Hirsch is literally bringing from all over Shas Bavli, Yerushalmi, Tosefta, masechtos ketanos and more in order to discuss and refute their claims.

Thus this work is the best one for anybody who wants to see authentic sources which could be misinterpreted, while also seeing the proper way to read them as well.

Comment: How could you call Graetz and rabbi Frankel kofrim when both were observant Jews? Heinrich Graetz was even a famous Jewish historian and scholar.

Comment: @TurkHill What does one have to do with the other? If a person keeps Shabbos and kashrus and tefillin, is honest in business, etc., but believes that there are two gods, then his mitzvah observance doesn't make him any less of a min. Same thing, as the Rambam (whom you particularly like quoting) says, a person who "denies the interpretation of the Torah, namely the Oral Torah, or denies the authority of its transmitters, as Zadok and Boethus (the founders of Sadduceanism and Boethusianism) did" is a kofer, whether he actually keeps the mitzvos or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107610/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-meir).

Comment: This may not be true as scholars say that this was not the origin of the Sadduccees. The high priests (Sadduccees) in Second temple times were not members of the family of Tzadok. On the contrary, Tzedukim means “the righteous ones.”

Comment: @TurkHill Sorry, source for the claim that "Tzedukim" means "righteous ones" and _not_ "of Tzadok" (referring to the Sadducean sect)?

Comment: @Yehuda I cannot remember the source, but you can find the idea in academic sources.

Answer (score 4):

I have posed this question to 2 different judaic studies professors. Since these were private conversations I cannot disclose who they were. Both are very respected in their fields. One studies rabbinic literature and the other bible, and they both gave me more or less an identical response, which to me lends it more credence:

Early research into this topic was done at a time when few jews were in academia. Further, many academics were Christian and wanted to bifurcated rabbinic Judaism from second temple Judaism as a pro Christian polemic. Modern academics today reject this view as biased and untenable instead assuming a much closer relation between the 2.

In other words, the answer to your question is: none.
That doesn't mean there are no differences between pre and post the churban, just that the complete bifurcation between the 2 periods is a fabrication.

Answer (score -2):

Not a complete answer, but here is a source that hints it:

משנה הוריות ג ח

אבל אם היה ממזר תלמיד חכם וכהן גדול עם הארץ, ממזר תלמיד חכם קודם לכהן גדול עם הארץ.

Mishna Horayot 3:8

If The *Mamzer*  is *Talmid Hacham* , and the prime priest is *Am Haartz* the *Mamzer* takes precedence [to be released from kidnappers]

בבלי הוריות יג א

מה"מ א"ר אחא ברבי חנינא דאמר קרא (משלי ג, טו) יקרה היא מפנינים מכהן גדול שנכנס לפני ולפנים

Babvli Horayot 13:a

Where it comes from? Rabbi Aha son of Rabbi Hanina says: the verse (Proverbs 3:15) says [the Tora] is more important than pearls (Hebrew: *Pninim*) - Meaning from the prime priest who enters to the interior [*Kodesh HaKodashim*] (Hebrew: *Lifnai U'Lifnim*)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is relevant -- it's stating only that ransoming a Torah scholar takes precedence over ransoming the high priest, and only because Torah is more precious than the service of the high priest. Why would anyone conclude from this that Torah / Judaism has evolved in some way?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Some might will say you are absolutely right, some will call you naive. Where in *Vaykra*, that praises the priests, there is a hint that a scholar is more impotent?

Comment: Are you saying that Chazal placed higher importance on Torah scholars in order to promote "Rabbinic Judaism"? I would suggest you make that connection explicit in your answer.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I say things change. Also, if Chazal hinted that, why would I say it explicitly?

Comment: Hopefully you are aware that you are not Chazal, and also that your audience is a _slightly_ different one.

Answer (score -8):

Normally anceint books by well-respected rabbis work for sources. Although this is not an anceint book, I think it is well-written and might contian the sources you're looking for.

Rabbi Binyamin Lau's four volumes called “The Sages” explains the development of the Oral Law by the Pharisees and Rabbis. He feels that the changes were made because of the necessities of the later time. He does not criticize the rabbis since the changes were made in the spirit of the Torah and that a careful reading of the Torah shows that it wants to be updated. For example, Maimonides felt that G-d neither needs nor wants sacrifices but “allowed” sacrifices to continue. But this is not an ideal mode of worship and will not be reinstituted when people become more sophisticated. You could apply the same to the laws of slavery, rape, and captive women. In short, we are not Torah Jews but Rabbinic Jews.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to bring only a second-hand source? Is it possible that actually looking at the original sources might suggest a different conclusion? DV.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I do not remember the sources, but they are many. Rabbi Lau wrote a few books which contain many sources. I would add that an argument could be made that Ruth did not convert because she is never called a Jew. No conversion procedure is mentioned. Later laws have such a procedure. It follows that Ruth never converted because she did not have these later laws developed by the rabbis. Lastly, ibn Ezra notes that Deuteronomy is Moses's reform of the Decalogue. Thus Moses began the Oral Law forty years after Sinai. ibn Ezra was the first Bible critic.

Comment: Also, the Sadducees did not accept the Oral Law. But as I explained previously, a careful reading of the Torah suggests that it demands to be updated. The "Oral Law" is divine mitzvot because they are made in the spirit of the Torah and that this is what G-d wants. Thus, for this reason, G-d favored the Pharisees and later rabbis.

Comment: The Sadducees in Hebrew are called Tzedukim, based on the word tzedek, meaning ‘righteous.'

Comment: Presumably both you and Binyamin Lau pray three (and sometimes four and five) times a day that G-d should "restore the service to the inner rooms of Your House, and the sacrifices of Israel and their prayers speedily, with love You will accept with desire" -- והשב את העבודה לדביר ביתך ואשי ישראל ותפלתם מהרה באהבה תקבל ברצון. Assuming you aren't lying when asking for this, I'm curious to know what verbal gymnastics you would use to explain it.

Comment: @ZevSpitz We still have many references in the siddur praying for the restoration of sacrifices. But the siddur is a compendium of many often conflicting ideas, which prompt us to think and to remember the past.

Comment: @TurkHill no, it's really not. You've said that several times but you don't bring a single example of prayers that contradict each other.  There are peripheral parts like piyutim but the core parts of the siddur are quite consistent.

Comment: @Heshy Prayers are like Midrashim, they express views differently. There are many commentaries that differ in prayers, even in the Talmud we find conflicting views. There is not one thing that every Jew agrees. There is virtually a dispute on everything. Jew differs about mysticism, rationalism, reform, and even G-d. For example, mystics say that G-d has parts while rationalist insist that G-d is one.

Comment: @TurkHill "Tzdokim" comes from the name of the progenitor of the group, a man called Tzadok. Presumably his parents hoped he would be righteous, but from what the gemara tells us about him and his followers, it doesn't sound like either of them lived up to the name.

Comment: @TurkHill if that's the case then it shouldn't be hard for you to find two prayers that contradict each other.

Comment: @Heshy Yes, Sadducees, Hebrew for Tzedukim, could denote the family of Tzadok who ran the temple. Those who say that this is the case say that the Tzedukim did not follow the Torah. This helps back up the claim that the Pharisees did not add or change but was following the Oral Torah of Moses, as well as the written Torah. People who like this claim say that the Sadducees were not following old traditions but deviated, insisting a more literal reading of the Torah. This view is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Many scholars say that this was not the origin of the Sadduccees. They insist that the high priests in Second temple times were not members of the family of Tzadok. Tzedukim means “the righteous ones,” those who observe the written Torah, not Perushim, “those who departed [from the literal understanding of Torah].” The Sadducees objected to the changes. The  Pharisees insisted that these were not changes [reforms] but were implementing the Oral Law. The Sadducees objected, saying that this notion of an Oral Torah is itself an invention; it had never been mentioned until then.

Comment: @TurkHill I'm not aware of any other contemporary sources regarding the Sadducees and ascribing a different origin to them, other than the gemara and perhaps some midrashic sources (all Pharisee-based sources, obviously). But anyway, I did not say they were descendants of Tzadok but were his *followers*. And yes, most of them were kohanim. They were considered the snobbish elite of the Second Temple era. Yeah, of course they considered themselves "righteous", but *were* they?

Comment: @Heshy I do not think it can be said with any certainty that the Sadducees were the followers of Tzadok since the Tzadok no longer existed during Second Temple times. Scholars have noted that their name in Hebrew is Tzedukim, which means “the righteous ones.” Whether or not they were truly righteous is the debatable. I think, and this is my opinion, that the Pharisees, and later rabbis, were more righteous because they changed the laws for the necessities of the later times.

Comment: @TurkHill the comments were deleted but I'd like to challenge you again: can you find two prayers _that existed in Rambam's version of the prayers_ that contradict each other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107114/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-zev-spitz).